# Vagrant box update - issue

Tags: vagrant, box

I am using Vagrant 1.85 and at some point I get the message teling me to upgrade my box version of ubuntu/trusty64 here is the message:

```
==> web02: A newer version of the box 'ubuntu/trusty64' is available! You currently
==> web02: have version '20160818.0.0'. The latest is version '20160822.0.0'. Run
==> web02: `vagrant box update` to update.
```

So I ran the command `sudo vagrant box update` and this is the message I get:

```
==> web02: Checking for updates to 'ubuntu/trusty64'
    web02: Latest installed version: 20160818.0.0
    web02: Version constraints: 
    web02: Provider: virtualbox
==> web02: Updating 'ubuntu/trusty64' with provider 'virtualbox' from version
==> web02: '20160818.0.0' to '20160822.0.0'...
==> web02: Loading metadata for box 'https://atlas.hashicorp.com/ubuntu/trusty64'
==> web02: Adding box 'ubuntu/trusty64' (v20160822.0.0) for provider: virtualbox
/opt/vagrant/embedded/lib/ruby/2.2.0/rubygems/version.rb:206:in `initialize': Malformed version number string temp (ArgumentError)
    from /opt/vagrant/embedded/lib/ruby/2.2.0/rubygems/version.rb:198:in `new'
    from /opt/vagrant/embedded/lib/ruby/2.2.0/rubygems/version.rb:198:in `new'
    from /opt/vagrant/embedded/gems/gems/vagrant-1.8.5/lib/vagrant/box_collection.rb:284:in `block (3 levels) in find'
    from /opt/vagrant/embedded/gems/gems/vagrant-1.8.5/lib/vagrant/box_collection.rb:284:in `each'
    from /opt/vagrant/embedded/gems/gems/vagrant-1.8.5/lib/vagrant/box_collection.rb:284:in `all?'
    from /opt/vagrant/embedded/gems/gems/vagrant-1.8.5/lib/vagrant/box_collection.rb:284:in `block (2 levels) in find'
    from /opt/vagrant/embedded/gems/gems/vagrant-1.8.5/lib/vagrant/box_collection.rb:283:in `each'
    from /opt/vagrant/embedded/gems/gems/vagrant-1.8.5/lib/vagrant/box_collection.rb:283:in `block in find'
    from /opt/vagrant/embedded/gems/gems/vagrant-1.8.5/lib/vagrant/box_collection.rb:436:in `block in with_collection_lock'
    from /opt/vagrant/embedded/lib/ruby/2.2.0/monitor.rb:211:in `mon_synchronize'
    from /opt/vagrant/embedded/gems/gems/vagrant-1.8.5/lib/vagrant/box_collection.rb:435:in `with_collection_lock'
    from /opt/vagrant/embedded/gems/gems/vagrant-1.8.5/lib/vagrant/box_collection.rb:268:in `find'
    from /opt/vagrant/embedded/gems/gems/vagrant-1.8.5/lib/vagrant/action/builtin/box_add.rb:302:in `box_add'
.....
```

The upgrade does not seems to complete could some explain me whats this actually meens?

Thank you
Perry

Comment: why you need sudo ? just run `vagrant box update` it will download the newest version of the box

Comment: Also, it appears that Hashicorp's misguided idea of 'all-in-one packaging' might be having issues again.